# sql left join on same table

Tags: sql

```
|-------------|------------|
| employee_id | team_id    |
|:------------|:-----------|
|     1       |     8      |
|     2       |     8      |
|     3       |     8      |
|     4       |     7      |
|     5       |     9      |
|     6       |     9      |
|-------------|------------|
```

Write an SQL query to find the team size of each of the employees.

```
SELECT a.employee_id, COUNT(b.team_id) AS team_size
FROM Employee a LEFT JOIN
     Employee b
     ON a.team_id = b.team_id
GROUP BY a.employee_id
```

The answer above is correct I am just confused as to why you use a LEFT JOIN on two tables that are the same.

Comment: This is a self-join.  I really don't understand your question.  Do you not understand the concept of "self-join"?  Do you not understand the query?  Do you not know how to write a query to answer the question?

Comment: In your example, it's a basic list of all employees showing the total size of the team in which the employee exists.  In this case, the JOIN on the same table, using the "team_id" column as the joining reference, is returning all of the records in the "Employee" table that have the same "team_id" value as each current employee.  If the joined table was not there, and you just did a count of "team_id", you'd get "1" on every row, because the count would be in the context of the each single employee's row.  It's a fairly basic method to use when you're aggregating

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to understand what is happening is to just view the intermediate table which results from the self join.  It looks something like this:

```sql
+---------------+-----------+---------------+-----------+
| a.employee_id | a.team_id | b.employee_id | b.team_id |
+---------------+-----------+---------------+-----------+
|     1         |     8     |     1         |     8     | \
|     1         |     8     |     2         |     8     |   3 members
|     1         |     8     |     3         |     8     | /
|     2         |     8     |     1         |     8     | \
|     2         |     8     |     2         |     8     |   3 members
|     2         |     8     |     3         |     8     | /
|     3         |     8     |     1         |     8     | \
|     3         |     8     |     2         |     8     |   3 members
|     3         |     8     |     3         |     8     | /
|     4         |     7     |     4         |     7     | - 1 member only
|     5         |     9     |     5         |     9     | \
|     5         |     9     |     6         |     9     | / 2 members
|     6         |     9     |     5         |     9     | \
|     6         |     9     |     6         |     9     | / 2 members
+---------------+-----------+---------------+-----------+
```

The self left join causes each employee record on the left side to be replicated however many times there are other employees on the same team.  Then, aggregating by employee and taking the count of records gives the sizes of each employee's team.  In the intermediate table above, we can see this happening in progress.